# Auto line break in PhpStorm in <p> tag

Tags: html, phpstorm, webstorm

What could be the possible setting in PhpStorm to fix this auto line break of paragraph tag?

[image]

Comment: Is this a setting or have you minimized your screen?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The fact that it makes new line after "The Oslo Times." ? or that symbol after "He attended"? So far the code looks formatted by the right margin (so when text gets over the right margin the line breaks. That souls be configurable in `Code Style | HTML` in PhpStorm's Settings/Preferences.

Comment: also, please make sure that `Use soft wraps` is not enabled in  **Settings | Editor | General** and **View | Active editor**

Comment: @LazyOne yes the problem is that it makes new line after "The Oslo Times".

Comment: @lena disabling soft wraps seems the solution but it creates horizontal scrolling which i don't want. Help me out..

Comment: that's the expected behavior - you need to either scroll the editor or wrap the code to see the code that doesn't fit the window size.